# Recyclerview data to marker in Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent, android-recyclerview

**SearchAdapter**

```
public class SearchAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SearchAdapter.SearchViewHolder> {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<String> studentNameList;
    ArrayList<String> studentMatrikList;
    ArrayList<String> studentPhoneList;
    ArrayList<String> studentAddressList;
    ArrayList<String> studentLatList;
    ArrayList<String> studentLngList;

    class SearchViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView studentName, studentMatrik, studentPhone, studentAddress, studentLat, studentLng;
        CheckBox checkBox;
        Button buttonMap;



        public SearchViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            studentName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.studentName);
            studentMatrik = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.studentMatrik);
            studentPhone = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.studentPhone);
            studentAddress = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.studentAddress);
            studentLat = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.studentLat);
            studentLng = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.studentLng);
            checkBox = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
            buttonMap = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.buttonMap);
            checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
                    if (isChecked) {
                        Toast.makeText(SearchAdapter.this.context,
                                "Selected student is " + studentName.getText(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {

                    }
                }
            });
        }

    }

    public SearchAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> studentNameList, ArrayList<String> studentMatrikList, ArrayList<String> studentPhoneList, ArrayList<String> studentAddressList, ArrayList<String> studentMailList, ArrayList<String> studentConList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.studentNameList = studentNameList;
        this.studentMatrikList = studentMatrikList;
        this.studentPhoneList = studentPhoneList;
        this.studentAddressList = studentAddressList;
        this.studentMailList = studentMailList;
        this.studentConList = studentConList;

    }

    @Override
    public SearchAdapter.SearchViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_layout, parent, false);
        return new SearchAdapter.SearchViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(SearchViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.studentName.setText(studentNameList.get(position));
        holder.studentMatrik.setText(studentMatrikList.get(position));
        holder.studentPhone.setText(studentPhoneList.get(position));
        holder.studentAddress.setText(studentAddressList.get(position));
        holder.studentLat.setText(studentMailList.get(position));
        holder.studentLng.setText(studentConList.get(position));
        holder.buttonMap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, MapsActivity.class);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        return studentNameList.size();
    }
}
```

Textview Address Value:

```
studentAddress = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.studentAddress);
```

Textview Latitude Value:

```
studentLat = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.studentLat);
```

Textview Longitude Value

```
studentLng = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.studentLng);



 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(SearchViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.studentName.setText(studentNameList.get(position));
        holder.studentMatrik.setText(studentMatrikList.get(position));
        holder.studentPhone.setText(studentPhoneList.get(position));
        holder.studentAddress.setText(studentAddressList.get(position));
        holder.studentLat.setText(studentMailList.get(position));
        holder.studentLng.setText(studentConList.get(position));
        holder.buttonMap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, MapsActivity.class);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
```

Is it possible to link the buttonMap and show marker in Google Maps based on textview address or latitude and longitude? I ask this before but can't find solution...

Comment: you mean,you want to show marker on googlemap activity when i click on recylerview button i am right

Comment: @Gowthaman M yes the marker will based on the textview address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 holder.buttonMap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, MapsActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("address",holder.studentAddress..getText().toString();)
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

**MapsActivity.class**

Inside Oncreate()

```
String searchAddress = getIntent().getStringExtra("address");
```

**If you want to place your address in google map then easy way to use following**

```
Intent searchAddress = new  Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q="+address));
startActivity(searchAddress);
```

**(or)**
Use this below method to get lat and lng from the address then make marker into your google map...if you are not getting lat lng value means you address invalid..

```
public GeoPoint getLocationFromAddress(String searchAddress){

Geocoder coder = new Geocoder(this);
List<Address> address;
GeoPoint p1 = null;

try {
    address = coder.getFromLocationName(searchAddress,5);
    if (address==null) {
       return null;
    }
    Address location=address.get(0);
    location.getLatitude();
    location.getLongitude();

    p1 = new GeoPoint((double) (location.getLatitude() * 1E6),
                      (double) (location.getLongitude() * 1E6));

    return p1;
    }
}
```

**Try this below code to make marker into google map**

```
if (latitude != null && longitude != null)  
     {  
     mGoogleMap2.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()  
        .position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)));  
    mGoogleMap2.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(  
       new LatLng(latitude, longitude), 10));  
     }
```

> [Reference here how to get latlng from address](https://javapapers.com/android/android-geocoding-to-get-latitude-longitude-for-an-address/)

Comment: @JavaGuy I hope this may help you..if you have any pbm let me know...usefull donot forgot to upvote

Comment: thanks for answering... I try intent.putExtra("address",holder.studentAddress..getText().toString();) but get error saying Variable holder is accessed from within inner class

Comment: @JavaGuy  studentAddressList.get(position) just pass like this..make is position as a final int posti